# Trying to install wordpress locally with mamp, but have unsupported php version

Tags: php, local-installation

I am following this tutorial to set up wordpress locally with Mamp on https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_Locally_on_Your_Mac_With_MAMP

Holding by step 3:

> Step 3: Starting MAMP Servers & Creating The Database To start the
>   MAMP Apache and MySQL servers, simply click "Start Servers" from the
>   main MAMP screen. Your MAMP servers have now been started.
>
> Once the MAMP servers start, the MAMP start page should open in your
>   default web browser. If not, click on "Open start page" in the MAMP
>   window. Once that's open, select phpMyAdmin from the webpage.
>
> Under "Create new database", enter in a database name such as
>   "wordpress", and press "Create." No need to choose an option for
>   "collation"  : it will automatically be assigned by MySQL when the
>   database tables are created, during the WordPress installation.

I can't get into PHPMyAdmin because it requires PHP 5.5.X - 7.0.X and I have PHP Version 7.1.1.

I tried looking online how to downgrade, and I am afraid I will break everything as this is my first time doing this.

Any help is muchly appreciated.

Comment: Hello @madav - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! Unfortunately your question may be considered [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here as although it arose in the context of setting up a WordPress site, the question itself is regarding MAMP (WordPress certainly won't break if you switch PHP versions correctly). Your question would probably be best addressed in MAMP's official support channels. Please see the "[ask]" page in our [help] for more information.

Comment: Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41065984/phpmyadmin-mcrypt-error-on-php7-1#answer-41405027